# Material UI's Snackbar is not sliding down

Tags: material-ui, snackbar

I am using `Material-UI` for the first time and trying to implement `Snackbar` on success of an API post. I want the Snackbar to slide up onEnter and then slide down onExit. I was able to implement slide up onEnter but need help for "Slide down onExit". Can anyone help me?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

const [openSnackBar, setOpenSnackBar] = useState(false);   

const renderSnackbar = () => {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        id="id-success-snackbar"
        className="success-snackbar"
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        open={openSnackBar}
        autoHideDuration={5000}
        onClose={() => setOpenSnackBar(false)}
        TransitionComponent={Slide}
        message="Test Message"
      />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `TransitionComponent` to a function that takes `TransitionProps` as its parameter and returns the `Slide` transition with those props spread onto it. From the Material UI docs [here](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#change-transition) in the "Change Transition" section, notice that the examples given render the `Slide` transition component as such:

```
function SlideTransition(props: TransitionProps) {
  return <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;
}
```

That's because the `TransitionComponent` prop of `Snackbar` takes in a callback of the same signature and applies the slide up animation to the snackbar this way.

Your code snippet should thus look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

const [openSnackBar, setOpenSnackBar] = useState(false);   

const renderSnackbar = () => {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        id="id-success-snackbar"
        className="success-snackbar"
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        open={openSnackBar}
        autoHideDuration={5000}
        onClose={() => setOpenSnackBar(false)}

        /* set this to the function below */
        TransitionComponent={slideTransition}


        message="Test Message"
      />
    );
};

// Function that should be passed to the TransitionComponent prop above
const slideTransition = (props: TransitionProps) => {
  return <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;
};
```

I too have found through my own experimentation that simply putting `<Slide />` or `Slide` in the prop allows the snackbar to animate onEnter, but not onExit. I hope this helps you or others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: Please note that the function of Slide must be the same function, i.e you cannot just put it inside a component directly, because it will change after re-rendering. The useState is not essential here, because you can just put the function outside the component to keep it unchanged.